# How can I test CanCan in the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I need to check :read? on an object in the console, how can I do this?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need to setup **Ability** object:

```
ability = Ability.new(current_user_object)
```

Now you check authorization:

```
ability.can? :read, object_to_be_checked
```

> **current_user_object:** User object for which you want to check authorization
>
> **object_to_be_checked:** is object on which you want to check authorization